# url::to(xxx/yyy) returns different results depending on context

Tags: laravel-4

I'm using the `URL::to` call to embed a link in an outgoing mail message. What I get when I do this is something like: "`baseroot/public/index.php/xxx/yyy`".

And yet when I do the same call, for example, within a `route` call, I get "`baseroute/xxx/yyy`".

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The source of `URL::to` resides at 
http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Routing.UrlGenerator.html#76-98

(linked to from http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Routing.UrlGenerator.html).

I suggest you add debug printing to your copy and see what values `$this->getScheme()` and `$this->getRootPath()` yield. These must be the source of the discrepancy, apparently caused by different `this` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with `URL::to('user/123')` returning an incorrect value when visiting the homepage vs. another page. After some investigation, ***in my case* it was a matter of case-sensitivity (!) in the request's url**. I hope it's somehow related to your mysterious case.

More about my case: `URL:to('user/123')` gave me different results whether I visited `http://localhost/`**`MyApp`**`/public/someurl` or `http://localhost/`**`Myapp`**`/public/someurl`. In the former it gave the *correct* result `http://localhost/MyApp/public/user/123`, while the latter gave the *wrong* result of `http://localhost/user/123`.

.

***From here, less important notes*** from my investigation, for future Laravel archaeologists. I hope I'm not talking all nonsense. I am new to Laravel, using a local Laravel 4 installation + WAMP on a Windows machine.

- `UrlGenerator`'s `to()` method uses `$root = $this->getRootUrl($scheme);`. The latter uses `$this->request->root();`, where request is `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`.
- `Request::root()` indeed defaults to a wrong value e.g. `http://localhost` when visiting someurl with the incorrect case.
- The culprit is `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` (in vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request.php). Its `getBaseUrl()` calls `prepareBaseUrl()`, and there the actual logic of comparing the requestUri with the baseUrl is finally performed.
- For the few archaeologists still following, in my case the `$baseUrl` was /MyApp/public/index.php while the `$requestUri` was /Myapp/public/someurl, which sadly led the code to not satisfy this conditional:

  if ($baseUrl && false !== $prefix = $this->getUrlencodedPrefix($requestUri, dirname($baseUrl))) {
  return rtrim($prefix, '/');
  }